# Run r script in background on Ubuntu server

Tags: r, shell, ubuntu

I am working on an ubuntu server. I have an R Script which will run for several days. How would I run it in the background - that when I log out it still runs?!

When I try `R script.R` it says `ARGUMENT 'script.R' __ignored__`

Comment: @Arun Hmm, screen’s development is pretty much abandoned, and tmux is essentially a spiritual successor. I suggest switching.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, to run an R script in batch mode, you have several possibilities; I use the following, which works well:

```
Rscript scriptname.r
```

This, however, will run the script in the foreground. This isn’t a problem in tmux per se — just run it in a background tab. However, you can of course run it in the background in the usual way — append `&`:

```
Rscript scriptname.r &
```

Again, this needs to be run inside tmux (or similar) to stay alive once you log out.

Comment: Running it in the background isn't going to keep it running when OP logs out

Comment: @MrBones As long as tmux is still running, this isn’t a problem. tmux is designed so that it continues running even when the user logs out.

Comment: It's not clear from that sentence that you're running in the background in tmux.

Comment: @MrBones The first version of OP’s question mentioned `tmux`. They now edited it so it’s no longer mentioned.

Comment: `tmux new -s test` and then `tmux attach -t test` and running from there `Rscript` should do it too, right?

Comment: @Chrissl Yes, absolutely. Those comments simply start and resume a named session.

Comment: If the script provides output to the standard output there could be a problem with the script running in the background if the user logs out, or even if the shell is closed. In that case it may be useful to redirect the output like in `Rscript scriptname.r > outfile &`

Comment: @RHertel you mean when i save from the script `.RData` files it wont save them?!

Comment: I rather mean a script that contains, e.g., a `print()` or `cat()` command; unless a specific device has been specified as output.

Comment: @Chrissl No, `.RData` and similar work fine. RHertel means cases where your script uses `cat`, `message` or similar messages to print stuff. Those will be written to the terminal unless you redirect them to a file as shown in the comment.

Comment: ah ok. Thanks a lot! How would I close the window after I created one with `tmux new -s test`, went into it with `tmux attach -t test`, started my script with `Rscript test.r`?! Something like `^b` does not work

Comment: @Chrissl [Ctr-b], [d] should work (it works for me).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nope, thought that would work for me as well. Well I just `x` it out an reconnect :-/ not very elegant though

Comment: @Chrissl Okay, that’s unfortunate. However, this is an issue unrelated to the running of the R script: even when R blocks input handling (for instance because it’s in a tight loop), key strokes are still relayed to tmux.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes thats unrelated :) I though I ask it quick since I got hold of an expert ;)

Comment: [Ctr-b], [d] works for me to detach a session while `Rscript` is running.